# Understanding AlphaBlending in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, alphablending

I have a 32bpp bitmap image which has an alpha channel with values ranging from 0-255. I am trying to display this in a window using win32 APIs (snippet of code I am using to display is appended).

I was reading the documentation and it turns out that for blending, in the case where I want to use per-pixel values, windows uses the following formula:

```
Dst.Red     = Src.Red   + (1 - Src.Alpha) * Dst.Red
Dst.Green   = Src.Green + (1 - Src.Alpha) * Dst.Green
Dst.Blue    = Src.Blue  + (1 - Src.Alpha) * Dst.Blue
```

This is weird. I would have expected it to use:

```
Dst.Red     =  Src.Alpha*Src.Red    + (1 - Src.Alpha) * Dst.Red
Dst.Green   =  Src.Alpha*Src.Green  + (1 - Src.Alpha) * Dst.Green
Dst.Blue    =  Src.Alpha*Src.Blue   + (1 - Src.Alpha) * Dst.Blue
```

because that is what creates the overlay effect (translucency).

Is my expectation correct? If yes, why is windows doing the blending in this manner? What am I missing here?

snippet of code I am using to paint the Layered Window:

```
            bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
            bf.BlendFlags = 0;
            bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;  
            bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;              
            POINT ptOrigin = { 0, 0 };
            SIZE windowSize = { 300, 300 };

            POINT ptZero = { 0, 0 };

            UpdateLayeredWindow(m_sThis->m_hWnd, dc, &ptOrigin, &windowSize,
                hdc, &ptZero, RGB(255, 255, 255), &bf, ULW_ALPHA);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183393(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Note that the APIs use premultiplied alpha, which means that the red,
>   green and blue channel values in the bitmap must be premultiplied with
>   the alpha channel value. For example, if the alpha channel value is x,
>   the red, green and blue channels must be multiplied by x and divided
>   by 0xff prior to the call.

So, you are right, but you have to do it by hand before.

Comment: Ah. The pre-multiplication makes sense now. But why would they keep it like this?

Comment: I wrote to fast probably. From the documentation again: 

"There is a good reason why it uses premultiplied alpha. It is just not efficient to multiply the source color by the source alpha every time for every pixel. It has to be done only once, since the color and alpha values are correlated. It is usually done during the creation of the image (PNG, for instance, uses premultiplied alpha), and will save a very costly multiplication for every pixel for every draw.
"